# Min Bend Orthogonal Knots

Tags: discrete-geometry, knot-theory, stick-knots, graph-theory, reference-request

I am seeking literature on 3D orthogonal drawings of knots,
especially *minimum bend* drawings.
An orthogonal drawing employs segments parallel to the axes of
a Cartesian coordinate system.
A *bend* is a vertex at which two segments meet orthogonally.
A *drawing* insists on simplicity in the sense that nonadjacent
segments are disjoint, and adjacent segments meet only
at their shared endpoint.

One can imagine first drawing a 2D projection with a minimal
number of crossings and then removing the crossings.
For the trefoil below, naive crossing-removal
increments the $8$ bends in the 2D drawing to $8 + 3 \cdot 4 = 20$
bends, but the trefoil can be drawn with $12$ bends:

          
[image]

I would be especially interested in algorithmic methods to derive
the right 3D drawing above from the left 2D projection.
Thanks for ideas and pointers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Chad Giusti calls these "Plumbers' Knots":

https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.2215

https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.4717

In the first paper Giusti gives the space of plumbers knots a natural stratification which is a CW-decomposition.  This allows him to enumerate components of the space (knot types) in a fairly algebraic manner.

---

![GiustiFig1][1]

     
<sup>(Image added by J.O'Rourke)</sup>

---

Comment: @Ryan: Great references!  I would never have thought of searching using the word "plumber"!

Comment: The first paper, "Plumbers' knots," has just been updated on the arXiv: [Abstract link](http://arxiv.org/abs/0811.2215).