# Graph embedding in 3D grid minimizing edge length

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

I know that arbitrary graphs can be [embedded trivially](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_embedding#Embeddings_of_graphs_into_higher-dimensional_spaces) in $\mathbb{R^3}$ and that planar graphs can be drawn on a plane using [Schnyder's grid embedding algorithm](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/gina/schnyder/) after triangulation. And then there is also the $(i, i^2, i^3)$ [moment curve approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_embedding#Embeddings_of_graphs_into_higher-dimensional_spaces)..

What I am looking for is a non-crossing embedding of arbitrary graphs in multiple coplanar two-dimensional layers within $\mathbb{R^3}$ (a stack of $\mathbb{R^2}$ planes, $\mathbb{R^2} \times \mathbb{Z}$, discretized $\mathbb{R^3}$, 3D grid) just like the moment curve. But to make things more interesting I'd like the resulting embedding to look *nice*, i.e. minimizing the number of layers needed for an embedding and/or minimizing edge length. (Probably I want an embedding in $\mathbb{Z}^3$ or an minimum node distance constraint $|v_i - v_j| \ge 1$ for this to make sense)

I am new to this, so pointers to literature or more appropriate search keywords are highly welcome too. Perhaps this is a special/relaxed case of *realization* where distances between neighbors should be $1$, or maybe it is something along the lines of [chip layout optimization](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01759038). Does it make a difference if the graph is sparse? Is there a theory about embedding planar graphs in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to get shorter edge length?

Comment: I came naturally to this thread; I realize it was created a long time ago. I'm also interested in 3D graph drawing, but only of complete graphs $K_n$ of $n$ vertices. The handbook speaks about some methods and algorithms for an arbitrary graph which optimizes some properties. I was wondering: is there any known methods of drawing "nicely" complete graphs, which has a closed form solution? If not, what about embedding in a higher dimensional space $\mathbb{R}^M$ with $M<N$? Thank you! P.S. I leave "nicely" open to interpretation:) Maybe it could be in the direction that the OP was asking, or mo

Comment: @JorgedelVal: Perhaps this might help: Devillers, Olivier, Hazel Everett, Sylvain Lazard, Maria Pentcheva, and Stephen K. Wismath. "Drawing $K_n$ in three dimensions with one bend per edge." In *International Symposium on Graph Drawing*, pp. 83-88. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg, 2005.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question StackExchange style:

The concept you are looking is called [geometric] **thickness** of a graph. As described in the *Handbook of Graph Drawing and Visualization* (p. 473) mentioned by Joseph O'Rourke's excellent answer:

> The thickness of a graph $\mathbf{G}$, denoted by $\theta(\mathbf{G})$, is the minimum $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that the edge set of $\mathbf{G}$ can be partitioned into $k$ planar subgraphs.

Or as in an [answer on planar graphs by David Eppstein](https://mathoverflow.net/a/7852/47356):

> [Thickness is] the minimum number of colors one needs to color the edges in a drawing of the graph in the plane such that edges of the same color do not cross.

Given such an edge coloring drawing the graph becomes a matter of drawing planar same-color subgraphs each on its own layer. Bad news is that obtaining the coloring or even testing for the minimum $k$ seems to be $\mathcal{NP}$-complete. Also edges are not necessarily short.

Indeed a more practical approach might be to construct an **orthogonal drawing** with known limits to both *bends* and *volume* (and therefore average edge length) as also suggested by Joseph O'Rourke. The *Handbook of Graph Drawing and Visualization* refers to various such constructions in chapter 14: *Three-dimensional drawing algorithms*.

Answer (score 2):

Let me offer two pointers.
First, a common optimization is to minimize the number of *bends* in an orthogonal
drawing.
For example, here is a 2-bend drawing of $K_7$:

          
[image: K7]

          
<sub>(Image from [S.-H. Poon's link](http://www.cs.nthu.edu.tw/~spoon/3G_Lab/Projects/ortho_drawing.htm).)</sub>

There are many papers on this topic. See also my MO question,
"[Min Bend Orthogonal Knots](https://mathoverflow.net/q/97116/6094)."

Second, there is a very good quite recent survey:

> *Handbook of Graph Drawing and Visualization*. CRC Press. 2013.
>   See the chapter by Vida Dujmović and Sue Whitesides,
>   "Three-Dimensional Drawings."
>   ([CRC link](http://www.crcpress.com/product/isbn/9781584884125))
>   
>             
>   [image: Handbook]

Comment: Your answer has been very helpful in many ways. I have a much better understanding of the actual problem now. Thank you!