# Bridges between geometry and combinatorics

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, gt.geometric-topology, discrete-geometry

Geometry and combinatorics are two different branches of mathematics. Does there exist any connection between them? In many cases, mathematicians solve some geometric problems by reducing them to a combinatorial language. What are the general techniques to convert a geometrical problem to a combinatorial one? What are the known examples in literature?
What will be some good references to learn these techniques?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be worth having a look at Geombinatorics Quarterly, https://geombina.uccs.edu/

Comment: This question is not a duplicate, but a subset of this question, which already has excellent answers: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/179120/approaching-convex-and-discrete-geometry-from-other-disciplines

Comment: If you search on "geometric combinatorics" at Amazon, you will find many books on this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend the work of Adiprasito, Huh and Katz:

> K. Adiprasito, J. Huh, E. Katz, Hodge Theory for Combinatorial
> Geometries, Annals of Mathematics 188 (2018), 381–452. [[arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.02888)]. [[Journal](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Ehuh/MatroidHodge.pdf)]

They actually use geometric intuition/techniques to solve problems in combinatorics (rather than using combinatorics to solve geometric problems).